# Meaning of "Are you gonna be happy."

Tags: meaning

- If you like space in the attic, are you gonna be happy.

This is a line from the Simpsons Season 15 Episode 1. Marge said the sentence as she gave Bart and Milhouse a box full of old comic books, which she'd found in the attic and determined to throw out. I was curious about why she said it in declarative tone. I checked few subtitles and they were all written that way. What does that sentence mean? Is it kind of suggestive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is interrogative, not declarative, but it is stated in a declarative tone. This is a complicated little quirk of English, in which we can arrange word order in the form of a question, but leave off rising final intonation (or, in print, the question mark) to indicate that this is not a question to anyone but part of an explanation.

Think of it as a form of rhetorical question. Another way to state the meaning would be

> If you like space in the attic, you are not going to be happy [leaving boxes of comic books around up there].

Stating it as Lisa did softens the presumption of deciding what will or won't make the listener happy, yet maintains the vitality of the premise.